# update-alternatives with services

Tags: debian

I'd like to install a service from a `*.deb` package, link to it using `update-alternatives`.  Then enable/start the symbolic link.  Are there any examples of this in the existing debian archive?  If not, how would one do this?

I'm doing this because I want to be able to deploy several versions of my software on the same machine, then use `update-alternatives` to choose which one runs.

Typical control files could look like this for something that uses `update-alternatives` and relies on debhelper for services:

```
# myapp99.postinst
update-alternatives --install \
    /lib/systemd/system/myapp.service myapp \
    /lib/systemd/system/myapp99.service 99

#DEBHELPER#
```

```
# myapp99.prerm
update-alternatives --remove myapp lib/systemd/system/myapp99.service

#DEBHELPER#
```

But the problem here is `#DEBHELPER#` will operate on `myapp.service` in `postrm` after I've already `update-alternatives --remove`d it.

I could move my `update-alternatives --remove` to after `#DEBHELPER#` in postrm, but I would still have a problem where purging an old unused package will stop/disable `myapp.service`.  I'm sure there are other things I'm not considering too.

Are there any packages in the existing debian archive which do what I'm trying to do?

I'm almost considering doing this without `debhelper`: Checking if the link exists before install, and enabling if new. Checking if the link exists after purging, and stopping/disabling/masking only if this was the last supplier of that service.  If that's the only way to go, that's fine... I'd just prefer to not re-invent the wheel and introduce bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A Debian code search suggests](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=update-alternatives%20.*service) that the only package which does something like this is [`iptables-persistent`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/iptables-persistent), and I don’t get the impression it’s trying to do anything like what you’re after.

I don’t have a sure-fire way of handling what you’re proposing; I would go about it differently:

- one possibility would be to not ship multiple services at all; instead, build a common package which ships a service, and have the service use a binary which is handled using alternatives;
- another would be to ship multiple services, but not set them up as alternatives, and rely on the administrator to use systemd features to choose which instance to enable.

In the latter case, `dh_installsystemd --no-enable` will come in useful (in `debian/rules`).

Comment: I love the idea about a single service, then `update-alternatives` on the binary.  That's so much better than what I was doing.